# Does coffee oxidize in a travel mug if there air left in the mug?

Tags: pour-over, freshness

I've been brewing an Ethiopian bean recently on the Fellow Stagg Pour Over, and experienced something interesting. When brewing fresh at home, the coffee has delicious fruit notes. However, I brewed it once and took it in a travel mug to work, while it had the same qualities, the fruitiness tasted stale, and more like "old fruit".

I'm wondering if this is due to the coffee degrading due to travel, or if it has oxidized by the leftover airspace in the cup (note: this particular cup has an air-tight seal for a lid).

To summarize, my question is, does coffee oxidize while traveling, and does the amount of headspace you leave in your travel mug affect how well the coffee travels?

[EDIT]

I believe this question has already been answered [here](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/367/chemically-whats-happening-to-coffee-after-its-brewed)

Comment: I am guessing that you used an insulated mug, because you like your coffee hot?

Comment: This is correct, though I think this question has been answered already: 
https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/367/chemically-whats-happening-to-coffee-after-its-brewed

Comment: Cool - a self-found dupe. Good find!

Comment: Yes, is there a way I can mark this as a duplicate? I believe that's something earned with reputation?

Comment: Well, in the there’s no difference in flagging / voting to close as duplicate and self-deleting the question - and unanswered  closed questions are deleted by the system after a while.

Comment: Is it best to self-delete then? or just flag as duplicate? Thanks for the advice though, it is appreciated.

Comment: Up to you. ^_^ And welcome to Coffee SE!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chemically, what's happening to coffee after it's brewed?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/367/chemically-whats-happening-to-coffee-after-its-brewed)